# How to call the window for selecting a geo-location in telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

In the mobile version of the telegram in "Geolocation", you can select any address on the map and send the data by pressing the "Send geolocation" button.

How can this functionality be invoked using a bot? sendLocation and sendVenue send a map with already specified latitude and longitude. How to make the user himself can choose the desired address?

I am using "php-telegram-bot" library

Answer (score 0):

There is `request_location` flag on [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) object. This will force users to send their current location (obtained by GPS). Otherwise you need to ask users to send google maps link.